# Polymorphism and array of pointers (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, inheritance, pointers, polymorphism

I have following classes: **Container**, **Element** and then couple of classes that **inherit** from Element, eg. **Button, Input**, etc ...

I have a problem when adding the elements to Container array, my main() looks like this:

```
Container c;
c.Add( Button(...) );
c.Add( Input(...) );
```

where "..." are some constructor parameters.

In the container class I have a array of pointers to store all elements that belong to that container:

```
Element ** elements;
```

But the problem I'm having is how to implement the Add method, I was hoping something like this would work:

```
void Add(const CControl & newElement){                      
    elements[elemCnt++] = &newElement;              
}
```

(the elements array is allocated: elements = new Element * [100];)

However I am getting this compilation error:

```
main.cpp: In member function ‘Container& Container::Add(const Element&)’:
main.cpp:138:23: error: invalid conversion from ‘const Element*’ to ‘Element*’
```

When I remove the const qualifier, I get a compilation error saying there is no suitable candidate.

The thing is, I am new to polymorphism and inheritance in C++, so I might be going wrong way about this. What would be the best approach on this?

PS: The main method must look the same, also don't suggest any vector or STL stuff.

Comment: What's wrong with using STL?  Why don't you want to use it??? It makes life so much easier

Comment: You make one major mistake here, and that is using the address of a _temporary_ variable and storing it away. The argument to `Add` is just temporary, and the object will be destroyed after the call is over. Besides that, I agree with @TonyTheLion, why not use the very good standard containers?

Comment: That's probably it, I'll need to copy the element and store the address of dynamically allocated copy.
I can't use STL because it's an assigment which is tested in enviroment without STL.

Comment: Voted to close as too localized. "Can't change `main`" is too localized a requirement.

Comment: Having a call with function(const type &something) is too localized? It was the point of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Add` should take a pointer:

```
void Add(CControl * newElement){                       
    elements[elemCnt++] = newElement;               
}
```

then you can call it like this

```
c.Add( new Button(...) ); 
c.Add( new Input(...) );
```

If you really cannot change the calling code, you need to somehow create a copy of the temporary.
E.g. by implementing a virtual `Clone` method in `CControl`, `Input`, `Button` an call it in `Add`.

```
void Add(const CControl & newElement){                        
    elements[elemCnt++] = newElement.Clone();
}
```

Comment: `elements[elemCnt++] = &newElement;` should be just `elements[elemCnt++] = newElement;`.

Comment: Problem is that I need to have the main() as is :/

Comment: Thanks! This worked. It's a bit weird but given the constraints is the only sensible thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to fix this code without changing `main`, because you attempt to store a reference to a temporary. This is undoable no matter what you do.